# navigate list from one page to another windows phone c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my windows phone application I have a list of contacts like below:

```
List<CustomContact> listOfContact1 = new List<CustomContact>();
```

And below is the `CustomContact` class :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using GetContacts.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;

namespace GetContacts
{
    class CustomContact
    {
        private string[] number = new string[5];
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //public string Number { get; set; }
        public string[] Number
        {
            get { return number; }
            set { number = value; }
        }
       // public string Number1 { get; set; }

        public CustomContact()
        {
        }

        //CTOR that takes in a Contact object and extract the two fields we need (can add more fields)
        public CustomContact( Contact contact)
        {
            Name = contact.DisplayName;
            int count = contact.PhoneNumbers.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (count > 0 && contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber))
                {
                    Number[i] = contact.PhoneNumbers.ElementAt(i).PhoneNumber.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                   Number[i] = "";
                }
            }
            /*var number = contact.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault();
                if (number != null)
                    Number = number.PhoneNumber;
                else
                    Number = "";*/
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to navigate list `listOfContact1` from my current page like below:

```
private void hyplnk_Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/createGroups.xaml?listOfContact1=" + listOfContact1, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

And want to retrieve from another page like below:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            List<CustomContact> listOfContacts = new List<CustomContact>();
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("listOfContact1", out listOfContacts ))
            {
                //do anything from list
            }
        }
```

But I am getting errors below

`Error 1: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,string>.TryGetValue(string, out string)' has some invalid arguments` at this line `NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("listOfContact1", out listOfContacts`

And

```
Error 2: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out System.Collections.Generic.List<GetContacts.CustomContact>' to 'out string' at this line `out listOfContacts`
```

How do 
I resolve it, I am following this link `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx` and Kindly suggest me How to navigate `list of contacts` from one page to another, waiting for your reply.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can at max pass objects using `NavigationService.Navigate`.

Also by using `State` as like:

```
    PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["Contact"] = Contact;
```

but here you want to pass list of that object which is not good programming practice.

You can have this collection as `public static` at Data model layer (layer atleast above UI layer) and then access it in next screen or anywhere in project.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know When you use the standard use of the NavigationService You cannot pass complex type parameter to another page using **QueryString**, You can try out the solution which is given here,

[Passing complex objects](http://www.vivien-chevallier.com/Articles/navigate-from-one-view-to-another-passing-a-complex-object-parameter-without-specifying-the-target-view-uri-in-a-windows-phone-7-application)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void hyplnk_Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  NavigationService.Navigate("/createGroups.xaml?listOfContact1=1", listOfContact1); 
}
```

The listOfContact1 = 1 is just used to fetch it on the other page.

This is how you add your list to the uri.

and when you successfully navigate to your page createGroups.xaml there in your `OnNavigatedTo` handler parse it this way :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) 
{ 
       // Store test data. 
       List<CustomContact> listContacts = new List<CustomContact>(); 


       // Request parameter. The identification of the source page. 
       string parameter = NavigationContext.QueryString["listOfContact1"]; 

       switch (parameter) 
       { 
           case "1": 
               var myParameter = NavigationService.GetLastNavigationData(); 


               if (myParameter != null) 
               { 
                   listContacts = (List<CustomContact>)myParameter; 
               } 
               break; 
       }
}
```

Hope this helps.

This link will give you additional details ::
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Pass-non-string-parameters-62ea2cc8
Thanks and Cheers.